# Example return for loop with onclick event

Tags: java, android

I'm making an application just to test the loops of repetitions and display on the screen after pressing a button.
In my code, if I use the TextView, it just displays the result in the case "10". If I use AlertDialog, displays 10 alerts which will regressing as I click.
How can I do to show the whole result? I wanted to solve this with both the TextView as AlertDialog. For example:
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0

What if I want to put a string together? for example:

name 10
name 9
name 8
name 7
name 6
name 5
name 4
name 3
name 2
name 1
name 0

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public void loopfor(View v){
        for(int nome =0;nome<=10;nome++){
            /*String stringint = Integer.toString(nome);
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setMessage(stringint);
            alertDialog.show();*/
            String stringint = Integer.toString(nome);
            textView.setText(stringint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What has this question to do with JavaScript?

Comment: You want to show dialog after dialog when the user hits ok. correct ?

Comment: I suggest also using more relative naming for your variables. "Nome" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is the TextView `append()` method. Replace:

```
textView.setText(stringint);
```

With:

```
textView.append(stringint + " ");
```

Then when you want to expand to the "name 10 name 9..." you can modify to the following:

```
textView.append(name + " " + stringint + " ");
```

Where "name" is a string variable.

Comment: Tks! Its worked for TextView. If I want show this same example using AlertDialog, what command I need use?@TronicZomB

Comment: For an AlertDialog, you could use the method that BigBrother provided. It should work well.

Answer (score 2):

Just append the string inside the loop and after that show your dialog with your full string:

```
public void loopfor(View v){
  String stringint = Integer.toString(nome);

    for(int nome =0;nome<=10;nome++){
       stringint = stringint+Integer.toString(nome); 

    }


   textView.setText(stringint); //or
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setMessage(stringint);
    alertDialog.show();*/


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void loopfor(View v){

    String stringint;
    for(int nome =0;nome<=10;nome++){
        /*String stringint = Integer.toString(nome);
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setMessage(stringint);
        alertDialog.show();*/
        stringint += "nome " + Integer.toString(nome) + " ";
    }
    textView.setText(stringint);

    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setMessage(stringint);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```